# escaping brackets and other characters in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I have run the following command on the command line and it works fine, but when I try running it from a shell script and run shell script from the terminal I get the following error:

`join -t $'\t'  -a1 -e "u" -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 file1  \
<(cat file2 | sort -k1,1|tr [:blank:] \\t ) |  awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\t"}{if \($2 == "u")print $0, $1;else print $0, $3}' | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\t");l=$4; sub(/.*_/,"",l); print $2"\t"$3"\t"l}' > out`

`syntax error near unexpected token`('`

I have tried escaping the bracket but it still gives me the same error. 
I have many of these multi-layered commands in the script so I am sure this will be a problem in other parts, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: And I thought badly written `perl` was read-only....

Comment: running that code gives me different errors (for example, `awk: cmd. line:1: ^ backslash not last character on line`). Are you _sure_ that you have provided the code you are really running?

Comment: What you see here is the state of the art before Perl. Perl was created to improve on this.

Answer (score 1):

What you have lost is the trailing `)` on your *stdin* subclause. What I suspect you have gained is a headache trying to read your code.

Try this instead, which then lends itself to further optimisation because it's (more) readable:

```
tr '[:blank:]' $'\t' <file2 |
    awk '
        BEGIN { FS="\t"; OFS="\t" }
        { if ($2 == "u") print $0, $1; else print $0, $3 }
    ' |
    awk '
        { gsub(/ /,"\t"); l=$4; sub(/.*_/,"",l); print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" l }
    ' |
    sort |
    join -t $'\t' -a1 -e "u" -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 file1 - >out
```

Comment: Thank you...this gives me the error "join: file 2 is not in sorted order"...I have file1 sorted right before...mmm I don't know anymore...it gave me a huge headache and a sleepless night to try to create this code so I am really looking forward to running it...

Comment: @jamespower add another `sort` into the pipeline. I'll edit in a suggestion for you

Comment: I think it is because the commands this way are flipped... I am doing all of the operations after the merging not only to one file...